# Xamarin Forms | Android: BitmapDescriptor Error - Image must be a Bitmap

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use `GroundOverlayOptions` to add a custom image to my `Android.gms.maps`

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromPath("fire2.bmp");

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new 
GroundOverlayOptions().InvokeImage(image);
newarkMap.Position(e.Point, 8600f, 6500f);
map.AddGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

Despite `fire2.bmp` being a bitmap, I am still receiving the error:

`Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.`

What am I missing?

Comment: use `fire2.png` or `fire2.jpg`, not `fire2.bmp`

Comment: Unfortunately its the same error if I use fire2.png

Comment: ooops, ok, you have to provide the full path i think - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromPath(java.lang.String): `absolutePath - The absolute path of the Bitmap image.`

Comment: You may insert a break point at `BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromPath("fire2.bmp");` and run the code to check whether this `image` correct is or not.

Comment: Your png image have to be in the Assests folder instead of the Resources/Drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource. If at compile time you don't get any errors that means your resource exists and will be found at runtime